# My database query security

Tags: php, mysql, security

I am new to web design, and I'm using a very simple ajax method to get the id of a product from a database. Being so new to backend stuff, I was wondering if anyone wouldn't mind teaching me a little about php security.

My first area in question is the post method and the method in which i get the data for the post method.

```
function setupc(upc) {
    var sku1 = $("#option1 option:selected").data('sku');
    var sku2 = $("#option2 option:selected").data('sku');
    if (sku2 !== null) {
        upc = (sku1 + sku2);
    } else {
        upc = (sku1);
    }
    $('input[name="upc"]').val(upc);

    $.post('getproduct.php', {upc: upc}, function(data){
        $('.result').html(data);
    });
}
```

And here is the getproduct.php

```
<?php
require_once("config.php");

$con=mysql_connect (MySQL, $username, $password);
if (!$con) {
    die("Not connected : " . mysql_error());
}
$db = mysql_select_db($database, $con);
if (!$db) {
    die ("Can\'t use db : " . mysql_error());
}

$upc = "$_POST[upc]";

$sql = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE upc = '$upc'";
$result = mysql_query($sql, $con) or die(mysql_error());
$row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
?>
<input type="hidden" id="id" name="id" value="<? echo $row['id']; ?>">
<input type="text" id="price" value="<? echo $row['price']; ?>">
<?php mysql_close($con); ?>
```

**If this is not the place to ask these kinds of questions, please let me know and I'll gladly remove it. And, maybe even point me to a place that i can.**

Comment: Yep, you script is vulnerable to SQL injections via `$_POST['upc']`.

Comment: If you switch to `mysqli` or `pdo` and use parameterized queries, many security worries disappear. It can be hard to write SQL queries correctly using the mysql_* api, so why bother when it's deprecated.

Comment: Before you write **any** more SQL interfacing code, read up on [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) and how to [properly escape your values](http://bobby-tables.com/php). You should **not** be using `mysql_query` in new application code, it's deprecated and being removed from PHP. [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and will provide a number of benefits when you're disciplined about using parameterized queries.

Comment: Thanks for the input! I'm very grateful for all the advice. I have a lot of studying to do.

Comment: If you're just getting started with PHP, instead of building an application from the ground up, pick a [popular framework](http://www.phpframeworks.com/top-10-php-frameworks/) and spend your time learning that. Most have a large amount of community code you can leverage when building your applications, saving you an enormous amount of time when it comes to adding features that are already solved problems.

Comment: [The Great Escapism (Or: What You Need To Know To Work With Text Within Text)](http://kunststube.net/escapism/)

Comment: This question appears to be better suited for http://codereview.stackexchange.com.


Answer (score 0, accepted):

your code doesn't prevent so-called "SQL injection"

This means that someone can call your script with sql-statements in the
$_POST['upc'] parameter

Your query would be better using mysql_real_escape_string:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE upc = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($upc) . "'";
```

any sql code would be escaped and won't be executed.

EDIT: you also may google for "SQL injection" a little bit, to learn about this security matter

Comment: Thank's for the input! This is very useful I'll be googling injections. I've heard of them while building this stuff but don't how it is done.